# How do I convert a string to an array name (php)?

Tags: php

I have 4 arrays, each with a question and answer. I want to select a random question/answer array. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$query_1 = array("What is two plus three?", "5");
$query_2 = array("What is four plus two?", "6");
$query_3 = array("What is seven plus one?", "8");
$query_4 = array("What is six plus three?", "9");

$rand_key = rand(1,4);
$current_query = ('$query_'.$rand_key);
$question = $current_query[0];

print $question;
?>
```

$question simply prints "$" rather than the first element of the array. How do I get $question to print the first element of the array?

-- yes, I'm a php noob.

Comment: whey did you assign like this ? $question = $current_query[0]; i mean offset 0 ?

Comment: @Milap: Because the OP thought that `$current_query` would hold the _value_ of the variable named '$query_2' (for instance), whereas it simply holds the string "$query_2" and accessing it using square bracket syntax (like an array) returns the character at offset 0 (in this case), which is "$".

Answer (score 5):

This is probably a more straight-forward way of accomplishing your task. Instead of storing each question in its own array and fetching it dynamically (i.e. `'question' . $random_value`) store each question and answer in the same array and take advantage of `array_rand()`.

```
<?php
$questions[] = array("What is two plus three?", "5");
$questions[] = array("What is four plus two?", "6");
$questions[] = array("What is seven plus one?", "8");
$questions[] = array("What is six plus three?", "9");

$randomKey = array_rand($questions); // Returns a random key from $questions
$question = $questions[$randomKey];

print $question[0]; // Question
print $question[1]; // Answer
```

Answer (score 3):

Fix your source:

```
$rand_key = rand(1,4);
$current_query = ${'query_'.$rand_key};
$question = $current_query[0];

print $question;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$qa = array(
array("What is two plus three?", "5"),
array("What is four plus two?", "6"),
array("What is seven plus one?", "8"),
array("What is six plus three?", "9")
);

$rand = rand(0,count($qa)-1);

print $qa[$rand][0];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use brackets.

```
$question = "{$current_query[0]}";
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current data structure, you need to use [Variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)...

```
$current_query = 'query_'.$rand_key;  // Removed $ prefix in front of 'query'
$question = ${$current_query}[0]      // Variable variables
```

The name of your variable is stored in `$current_query`, by placing another `$` in front of this you are accessing the value that is stored in a variable of that name. The curly braces (complex syntax) avoids any ambiguity ie. You are not referring to the name of a variable stored in the first element of an array.

However, there are better ways to store your data, such as suggested by @Mike B

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
eval("\$question = ".$current_query."[0];");
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. I figured there was a function for this, but wasn't able to find it.

Comment: @jshock: You should use [variable variables](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) rather than `eval()` in this instance. Quicker and safer.